# In Java, how do you parse a a string into a number with a value?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that takes the users input as a string. Within that string, if i know the position of where the number is, how do i separate the number with its value saved as a variable?

Answer (score 2):

```
int newValue = Integer.ParseInt(string.substring(begin, end));
```

`begin` is the position where the number begins. `end` is the position where it ends. Note that the first character is 0, second is 1, nth is n-1, etc, etc.-

You can also get a double:

```
double newValue = Double.ParseDouble(string.substring(begin, end));
```

Comment: Thanks!That helps A LOT... But is there a way to get a double(decimal)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the integer part out of the string using regex `"[\\D]"` and then convert the integer string to int value. Something like :

```
try {
int val = Integer.parseInt(strValue.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

}
```

Comment: No, the user knows the number may be part of the string. You need to split first.